# how to detect changes at custom widget in sf schema?

Tags: typescript, ng-alain

When I was working with sf component of ng-alain, I want to create a custom widget and don't know how to pass the value from my widget to sf and handle it. Here is the code:

```
schema = {
properties: {
  p1: {
    title: 'title',
    type: 'number',
    ui: {
      widget: 'my-widget',
      change: value => console.log(value)
    } as MyUISchema
  }
}
```

I don't know how to code about 'change' in my widget component.

Comment: I have solved this problem, you can add codes like below in your widget component. Here is the code:
//where you want to pass the value
`this.ui.change(value)`

Comment: Just so you know, you can answer your own question if you solved it!